# Google Vision privacy: image deletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision, vision

I'm planning to use Google Vision for document recognition.
For example, I will upload driver license and I should get all text data and verify that it is driver license and not the cover of a magazine.

The question is: does Google Vision has API for deletion of uploaded images?
Does Google Vision fit my case if I have some security requirements?

Comment: you're not a big fan of data privacy right? such documents are not supposed to be uploaded anywhere and there are many good reasons for that.

Comment: @Piglet Well I think that I'll finally pick standalone solution for this. Sadly, but you are 100% right.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it mainly deals with compliance requirements.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Google's mobile vision API, text and face detection is done on device rather than being uploaded:

https://developers.google.com/vision/

Answer (score 2):

For those who wondering the same problem, You can check their data policy here.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage

Answer (score 1):

My reading of [Google APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/) indicates that you will not be able to delete the images.

> 5b. Submission of Content
>
> Some of our APIs allow the submission of content. Google does not acquire any ownership of any intellectual property rights in the content that you submit to our APIs through your API Client, except as expressly provided in the Terms. *For the sole purpose of enabling Google to provide, secure, and improve the APIs (and the related service(s)) and only in accordance with the applicable Google privacy policies, you give Google a perpetual, irrevocable, worldwide, sublicensable, royalty-free, and non-exclusive license to Use content submitted, posted, or displayed to or from the APIs through your API Client. "Use" means use, host, store, modify, communicate, and publish. Before you submit content to our APIs through your API Client, you will ensure that you have the necessary rights (including the necessary rights from your end users) to grant us the license.*

Being able to "publish" your driver's licenses is probably not something you want.

The above terms are also completely at odds with the GDPR where the user has the right to delete and modify their data.

> 7a. Google Privacy Policies
>
> By using our APIs, Google may use submitted information in accordance with our [privacy policies](https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/).

Note that those privacy policies are the ones that govern normal users, not cloud specifically.  In plain text, and IANAL, it means that Google assumes that for whatever content you give them, the user has agreed to anything that Google does for a user that directly use, say Google Docs.

That's another indication that it's impossible to use their APIs and be GDPR compliant.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue

tl;dr **"*The stored image is typically deleted in a few hours.*"**

> Will the image I send to the Cloud Vision API, the results or other
>   information about the request itself, be stored on Google servers? If
>   so, how long and where is the information kept, and do I have access
>   to it? When you send an image to Cloud Vision API, we must store that
>   image for a short period of time in order to perform the analysis and
>   return the results to you. The stored image is typically deleted in a
>   few hours. Google also temporarily logs some metadata about your
>   Vision API requests (such as the time the request was received and the
>   size of the request) to improve our service and combat abuse.

Comment: Good quote. But note that "...the stored image is _typically_ deleted in a few hours" gives them permission to not delete the image at all! GDPR compliant OCR services such as ocr.space [guarantee](https://ocr.space/privacypolicy) the deletion directly after the ocr is done.

Comment: The wording of the data usage FAQ has been updated to reflect that Google does not retain the data. You can read more here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers a bit outdated so adding my own answer. The [data usage FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage) states

> When you send an image to Vision API, we must store that image for a short period of time in order to perform the analysis and return the results to you. For asynchronous offline batch operations, the stored image is typically deleted right after the processing is done, with a failsafe Time to live (TTL) of a few hours. For online (immediate response) operations, the image data is processed in memory and not persisted to disk.

If you use the synchronous Vision API methods, the image is never persisted in Vision API and so there is nothing to delete. If you use the asynchronous Vision API methods, the image is only persisted during the operation and is deleted immediately after the operation completes with a fail-safe of a few hours. Again there is nothing for the user to delete, Vision API takes care of deleting the data for you.

A related question that sometimes comes up is about enforcing usage to take palce in a particular region. You can see the answer here: [Google Vision: How to enforce processing in EU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160980/google-vision-how-to-enforce-processing-in-eu/59231610#59231610)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your security requirements, and the exact privacy law one needs to abide by. In my case, it was HIPAA, one needs to jump through a lot of hoops, but according to https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa, Google Cloud Vision API is a HIPAA covered product.