# Google Vision: How to enforce processing in EU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I am using google vision api. In order to support GDPR, I need the OCR to be processed in EU.
How can I enforce it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why this has a close vote, it's a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is available in the v1p4beta1 version of the Vision API. Using the following endpoints you can indicate that your file should be processed in the EU region:

For the annotate method: `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1p4beta1/{parent=projects/<your_project_id>/locations/eu}/files:annotate`

For the batch annotate method: `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1p4beta1/{parent=projects/<your_project_id>/locations/eu}/files:asyncBatchAnnotate`

This is documented for both [annotate](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1p4beta1/projects.locations.files/annotate) and [batch annotate](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1p4beta1/projects.locations.files/asyncBatchAnnotate), though it is a bit tricky to find these documents.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like this API is not supported in their JDK. even if I use the v1p4b package (e.g. com.google.cloud.vision.v1p4beta1.ImageAnnotatorClient) , there is no option to config the locations. I searched the web and didn't find.

Comment: I see. This is probably already in the road map for the Vision Client Libraries. However, opening a Feature Request in [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/java-vision/issues) or directly to [GCP](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1161261) may provide you with more visibility on ETAs and updates.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes), regional support has been added for OCR request.But the examples are not clear on how to specify the region.

Comment: I wonder whether the release notes talk about the region specification (so you can run OCR, with notion of region to improve results), or they are talking just about where does the processing is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the endpoint [eu-vision.googleapis.com](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/blob/master/samples/setEndpoint.js#L23). There is also a US endpoint. For examples of how to use see https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#regionalization

Comment: How do I do that from SDK?